# SQL query to create many-to-one tables from one table?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table like so:

```
column1 column2
------- -------
key1    value1
key1    value2
key1    value3
key2    value4
key2    value5
key2    value6
```

I would like to create the following two tables:

```
id column1
-- -------
1  key1
2  key2

key_id column2
------ -------
1      value1
1      value2
1      value3
2      value4
2      value5
2      value6
```

That is, I would like to split a table into a many-to-one relation between two new tables.

How would I write an SQL query to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the id column in your first new table is an identity column:

```
INSERT INTO NewTable1
    (column1)
    SELECT DISTINCT column1
        FROM OldTable;

INSERT INTO NewTable2
    (key_id, column2)
    SELECT n1.id, o.column2
        FROM OldTable o
            INNER JOIN NewTable1 n1
                ON o.column1 = n1.column1;
```

Answer (score -2):

Why don’t u use php my admin and enter the data manually. It will write the php for you.

Also your id field on each table must always be unique and auto incremented.

you cannot use 111 222 in a primary key